# Where is the memory allocated for p

Tags: go, reader

```
package main

import (
       "io"
       "os"
       "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
        r io.Reader
}

func (rot *rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
        n, err = rot.r.Read(p)     //<---- where allocated the mem for p?
        for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
                if p[i] >= 'A' && p[i] <= 'Z' {
                        p[i] = 65 + (p[i] - 65 + 13) % 26
                } else if p[i] >= 'a' && p[i] <= 'z' {
                        p[i] = 97 + (p[i] - 97 + 13) % 26
                }
        }
        return
}

func main() {
        s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
        r := rot13Reader{s}
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

This is an exercise from A tour of go. The code above can run properly, but I just don't understand where allocated the mem of p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

io.Copy will call the method Read() of the io.Reader, take a look to the implementation https://golang.org/src/io/io.go?s=12490:12550#L349 and if you keep reading just a few lines below you'll find the method copyBuffer() and inside you will see these lines:

```
if buf == nil {
    buf = make([]byte, 32*1024)
}

for {
    nr, er := src.Read(buf)

// ...more stuff
```